# i dont find angular 6 solution for how to convert ".expire" to typescript object

Tags: typescript, angular6

```
{
  "access_token": "eWcWLctGW-_NgGVAmFbO9l-nt3yztFzlZCLLlilI9mGDcM5q8d0kQw0uzvFOoXynHcb-MuPVJGTGkSkBhrr69_-aN1r5j9zB4fCl4u4aqOQ-scNI36xgHeGYpXky60drIBpMI83FGqd9pMjL4GWXjFHq61nhJ6xkGj1u1r9a5u6EJrB1lfjNhljzC_j65xaqxtubQ4AglKFO2ib-levpvnd_bEU-QGQrtvS2QbaXhb_hlnX8czo61Gn_OQyBVk7HbN1SozxIPe3RBvf5AiCAouDMz1WMHy9ybVFy8SnoNIgszjo7Ev2IEWS9aFb87u6bvoJvSVJv7s3z-2GUvG2kwfOk2sUWrmq0QeIJJrYwdKQfs3T8HrK2MNKSGteJ04-O",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1799,
  "refresh_token": "f1005c7fd74247069dbdb078ee379410",
  "as:client_id": "438dc832-33c7-413b-9c71-d0b98a196e6a",
  "userName": "master",
  ".issued": "Fri, 20 Jan 2017 14:30:09 GMT",
  ".expires": "Fri, 20 Jan 2017 15:00:09 GMT"
}
```

My question is how to map above json object to typescript object in angular 6. i.e how to create typescript class with above properties like .expire, as:client etc

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Foo {
  '.expires': string;
  'as:client_id': string;
}
```